# mysql run second query based on time stamp of an id from first query

Tags: mysql

I have a table "test". the stamp gets updated everytime table is updated.

```
id  |  text    |   stamp  
__________________________ 
1   |  textA   |   2012-11-06 01:06:34
2   |  textB   |   2012-11-06 01:01:34
3   |  textC   |   2012-11-06 01:03:34
4   |  textD   |   2012-11-06 01:05:34
5   |  textE   |   2012-11-06 01:02:34
6   |  textF   |   2012-11-06 01:08:34
7   |  textG   |   2012-11-06 01:09:34
8   |  textH   |   2012-11-06 01:04:34
```

I run a query 
"SELECT * from test ORDER BY stamp DESC LIMIT 3" (This returns rows with id 7,6 and 1)

Now I have the id of the last row returned (ie 1). How do I use that id to run a second query to fetch next 3 rows where the time stamp < stamp of id ?

Expected result is rows 4,8,3.

Comment: @actually I am learning mysql. I want to write something like "SELECT * from tests ORDER BY STAMP WHERE stamp < (stamp of row of ID) LIMIT 3. Not quite sure how to do it.

Comment: `WHERE stamp < (select id from test order by stamp desc limit 1,3)` would do the trick, but limits aren't supported in subqueries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id, text, stamp
FROM test 
WHERE stamp < (SELECT stamp FROM test WHERE id=1);
```

Comment: wonderful. It works. While reading on this, I came across joins. Do you think I should read further on it, or this is good enough?

Comment: @aVC: of course you should continue reading! :) There are situations where the above is good enough.  There are other situations where a join is more appropriate. One way to test the efficiency of your queries is to use `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.  You can see what the query plan is and compare it to the plan for an alternative query.